# Trying to load a jquery loading gif in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, gif

and I can't get mvc4 to recognize the Image location...

here is the code that I am using...

```
var $loading = $('<img src="Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
```

Putting in the @ symbol does not help... It only makes thing demonstrable worse. I then call this in a function...

```
$dialog
    .append($loading)
    .load($url)
    .dialog({
          autoOpen: false
        , title: $title
         , width: 1200
        , modal: true
       , minHeight: 350
         , show: 'fade'
         , hide: 'fade'
     });
```

In MVC2 I would simply just surround the `Url.Content()` in `<%= %>` tags and things would have been cool

this is the entire function...

```
function loadDialog(tag, event, target) {
            //debugger;
            event.preventDefault();
            var $loading = $('<img src="@(Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif"))" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
            debugger;
            var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
            var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
            $dialog.empty();
            $dialog
            .append($loading)
            .load($url)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false
                   , title: $title
                   , width: 1200
                   , modal: true
                   , minHeight: 350
                   , show: 'fade'
                   , hide: 'fade'
            });

            $dialog.dialog('open');
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work with Razor...

```
var $loading = $('<img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
```

I just assumed that this wouldn't work when moving the site from my developer box to an actual server.  Well, I am about to find out.

Answer (score 1):

must use @

```
var loading = '<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">';
```

Comment: So get rid of the parenthesese?

Comment: yes, at the end of the day you want append the img tag, so this works

Answer (score 1):

You should use @ and use single quotation ' instead of "

```
var $loading = $("<img src='"+@Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif")+"' alt='loading' class='ui-loading-icon'>");
```

---

***Update :***

**Or try this :**

```
var $loading = $('<img src="@(Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif"))" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
```

**And you should notice this wouldn't work in .js files**

Comment: That definitely doesn't work...  Using that @ sign always gets rid of the rest of my jquery... So nothing ever loads.

Comment: everything still cancels out.

Comment: Are you sure that you're putting this in cshtml file not in js file ?